# Getting True or False value for elements in a list from a dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Suppose we for example have these variables:

```
my_list = ["door_open", "AND", "dog_gone"], 
my_dict ={"door_open" : "false", "dog_gone" : "true", "dog_asleep" : "true"})
```

(Note, the list and dictionary could be longer or shorter and it should still work)
. And we want to be able to run it through this function:

```
def and_function(arg1, arg2):
    if arg1=="true" and arg2=="true":
        return "true"
    else:
        return "false"
```

How do we write a function that first will check if the elements in the list are "true" or "false", and then run it through the "and_function". This is somewhat what it should look like:

```
def interpret(my_list, my_dict):
#DO SOMETHING SO WE GET THE "true" OR "false" VALUE FOR ELEMENTS
.
. 
. 
if "AND" in my_list:
    return and_function(ture_or_false, false_or_true) 


"false"
```

Comment: By writing a *parser*. Please do not perform list processing, write an LL, LR, or LALR parser that parses a stream of tokens, and builds up the result, this is how a compiler evaluates expressions.

Comment: `and_function(my_dict[my_list[0]], my_dict[my_list[-1]])`?

Comment: @timgeb: what if the list contains `['foo', 'AND', 'bar', 'OR', 'qux']`

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem my question is designed to aim at what the actual scope of OP's question is. :)

Comment: I want to be able to extend for example my_list or my_dict and still have it working. But, yeah I will have to add that into the question. @timgeb

Comment: Well in that case... writing a parser it is. 

Answer (score 2):

This looks like a recursive structure (since likely the operands can be expressions as well). In that case writing a *parser* is a good idea. Writing a parser yourself is typically however error-prone and cumbersome. So we are not going to write the parser ourself, we use a tool that we can give specifications, and then generates the parser itself.

One of these tools is for example [PLY](http://www.dabeaz.com/ply/ply.html). A simple parser (I will not implement the full parser, but the idea should be clear), can look as follows.

## The *lexer*

First we need to implement a lexer that parses *tokens*:

```
# lexer.py

import ply.lex as lex

tokens = (
    'AND',
    'OR',
    'IDENTIFIER',
)

t_AND = r'AND'
t_OR = r'OR'

def t_IDENTIFIER(t):
    r'[a-z_]+'  
    return t

t_ignore  = ' \t\r\n'

lexer = lex.lex()
```

The above will result in a *lexer* (also known as a *tokenizer*; not a parser). A lexer turns a string into a list of tokens. Here there are three possible tokens: `AND`, `OR`, and `IDENTIFIER`. `AND` only matches `'AND'` (in uppercase), `OR` matches 'OR' (in uppercase), and `IDENTIFIER` matches anything that is a sequence of lowercase characters and underscores.

So if we parse a string, we get:

```
>>> from lexer import lexer
>>> lexer.input('foo AND bar')
>>> lexer.token()
LexToken(IDENTIFIER,'foo',1,0)
>>> lexer.token()
LexToken(AND,'AND',1,4)
>>> lexer.token()
LexToken(IDENTIFIER,'bar',1,8)
>>> lexer.token()
>>>
```

## The parser

Now we can turn the list of tokens into a "tree" that contains leafs (the identifiers) and *inodes* (the operands):

```
# parser.py

import ply.yacc as yacc

class Identifier:

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def resolve(self, dictionary):
        return dictionary[self.name]

class Node:

    def __init__(self, left, right):
        self.left = left
        self.right = right

    def resolve(self, dictionary):
        return self.func(self.left.resolve(dictionary), self.right.resolve(dictionary))

    def func(self, left, right):
        return None

class AndNode(Node):

    def func(self, left, right):
        return left and right

class OrNode(Node):

    def func(self, left, right):
        return left or right

from lexer import tokens

def p_expression_or(p):
    'expression : and_exp OR expression'
    p[0] = OrNode(p[1], p[3])

def p_expression_or_no(p):
    'expression : and_exp'
    p[0] = p[1]

def p_expression_and(p):
    'and_exp : ident AND and_exp'
    p[0] = AndNode(p[1], p[3])

def p_expression_and_no(p):
    'and_exp : ident'
    p[0] = p[1]

def p_ident(p):
    'ident : IDENTIFIER'
    p[0] = Identifier(p[1])

parser = yacc.yacc()
```

Here we specify a set of production rules together with the logic to handle this producction rule. We specify that an `expression` is an `and_expr` followed by an `OR` followed by an another `expression` (first function), or just an `and_expr` (second function). We thus build the grammar of the language. In the functions we the construct `AndNode`, `OrNode`, and `Identifier` objects in a tree-shaped way.

## Evaluating a *syntax tree*

Now we can parse the string into such tree with:

```
from parser import parser

tree = parser.parse('foo AND bar')
```

Now with a dictionary like:

```
data = {'foo': True, 'bar': True}
```

we can call the `.resolve(..)` method of the `tree`, and obtain the result:

```
>>> tree.resolve({'foo': True, 'bar': True})
True
>>> tree.resolve({'foo': True, 'bar': False})
False
>>> tree.resolve({'foo': False, 'bar': False})
False
```

## Extending the parser

If you read the documentation, you will find ways to include parenthesis, and other functions (unary operators, binary operators, functions), etc. to the lexer, parser and evaluate these.